# How to resize a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my application, I have a button that pushes a custom view controller (MenuViewController) on click.

```
@interface MenuViewController : UITableViewController
```

I wasn't able to resize the tableview.  I tried:

```
self.tableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,100, 100);
self.View.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,100, 100);
```

in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.  Neither of these methods worked.

I have an idea of creating a UIView initwithframe:.. and add MenuViewController as a subview.
Is this the proper way to do it?

MenuViewController is basically a general control that will handle variable init inputs
and will display the cells according to the inputs, the problem is the frame of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you inherit from UIViewController and expose the UITableView as a property and also on the Interface then you can resize it. When you are using UITableViewController then it will always display in full size mode.

UPDATE:

So instead of doing something like this:

```
@interface TasksViewController : UITableViewController
{

}
```

You can do something like this:

```
@interface TasksViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>
{

}

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Also make sure that in interface builder you have a UITableView which is hooked to the tableView property in the TasksViewController. Now in your implementation file implement the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and return the cell.

Comment: thank you for the reply, can you be more specific? if i exposed the UItableview as property, do i need to change the MenuViewController.m which basically inherits uitableview functions. a code snapshot would be helpful